# Will Ubuntu work on Asus X54HR-SX073V

Tags: asus

I bought an Asus X54HR-SX073V laptop, and I was thinking about getting Ubuntu as the OS for it.

Does anyone know will it work or not, and are there any compability problems with it?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it will. Linux kernel supports almost every hardware (95% of all hardware) . Install ubuntu without any fear.